# where is rotation policy of logs under /var/log/messages-*

Tags: logging, log-files, logrotate, log-rotation

I  would like to know how messages log file `/var/log/messages` are rotated.

I checked in `/etc/logrotate.conf` file and inside `/etc/logrotate.d/` directory but nothing that could explain the rotation.

Eg: This is a small part of messages file:

```
Oct 23 04:03:29 node2 grootd: DEBUG [groot.core.healthcheck.reactor] - added datanode[tcp-1:tcp]-1> to health table
Oct 23 04:03:29 node2 grootd: DEBUG [groot.core.healthcheck.reactor] - added datanode[tcp-1:tcp]-1> to health table
Oct 23 04:03:29 node2 grootd: DEBUG [groot.core.healthcheck.reactor] - added datanode[tcp-1:tcp]-1> to health table
Oct 23 04:03:29 node2 grootd: DEBUG [groot.core.healthcheck.reactor] - added datanode[tcp-1:tcp]-1> to health table
Oct 23 04:03:29 node2 grootd: DEBUG [groot.core.healthcheck.reactor] - added datanode[tcp-2:tcp]-2> to health table
Oct 23 04:03:29 node2 grootd: DEBUG [groot.core.healthcheck.reactor] - added datanode[tcp-2:tcp]-2> to health table
Oct 23 04:03:29 node2 grootd: DEBUG [groot.core.healthcheck.reactor] - added datanode[tcp-2:tcp]-2> to health table
Oct 23 04:03:29 node2 grootd: DEBUG [groot.core.healthcheck.reactor] - added datanode[tcp-2:tcp]-2> to health table
Oct 23 04:03:29 node2 grootd: DEBUG [groot.core.healthcheck.reactor] - added datanode[tcp-2:tcp]-2> to health table
Oct 23 04:03:29 node2 grootd: DEBUG [groot.core.healthcheck.reactor] - added datanode[tcp-2:tcp]-2> to health table
Oct 23 04:03:29 node2 grootd: DEBUG [groot.core.healthcheck.reactor] - added datanode[tcp-2:tcp]-2> to health table
Oct 23 04:03:29 node2 grootd: DEBUG [groot.core.healthcheck.reactor] - added datanode[tcp-2:tcp]-2> to health table
Oct 23 04:03:29 node2 grootd: DEBUG [groot.core.healthcheck.reactor] - added datanode[tcp-2:tcp]-2> to health table
Oct 23 04:03:29 node2 grootd: DEBUG [groot.core.healthcheck.reactor] - added JobHistoryServer[tcp-0:tcp]-0> to health table
Oct 23 04:03:29 node2 grootd: DEBUG [groot.core.healthcheck.reactor] - added JobHistoryServer[tcp-1:tcp]-1> to health table
Oct 23 04:03:29 node2 grootd: DEBUG [groot.core.healthcheck.reactor] - added JobHistoryServer[http-2:http]-2> to health table
Oct 23 04:03:29 node2 grootd: DEBUG [groot.core.healthcheck.reactor] - added journalnode[http-0:http]-0> to health table
Oct 23 04:03:29 node2 grootd: DEBUG [groot.core.healthcheck.reactor] - added journalnode[http-0:http]-0> to health table
Oct 23 04:03:29 node2 grootd: DEBUG [groot.core.healthcheck.reactor] - added journalnode[http-0:http]-0> to health table
Oct 23 04:03:29 node2 grootd: DEBUG [groot.core.healthcheck.reactor] - added journalnode[tcp-1:tcp]-1> to health table
Oct 23 04:03:29 node2 grootd: DEBUG [groot.core.healthcheck.reactor] - added journalnode[tcp-1:tcp]-1> to health table
Oct 23 04:03:29 node2 grootd: DEBUG [groot.core.healthcheck.reactor] - added journalnode[tcp-1:tcp]-1> to health table
Oct 23 04:03:29 node2 grootd: DEBUG [groot.core.healthcheck.reactor] - added mesos-slave[http-0:http]-0> to health table
Oct 23 04:03:29 node2 grootd: DEBUG [groot.core.healthcheck.reactor] - added mesos-slave[http-0:http]-0> to health table
Oct 23 04:03:29 node2 grootd: DEBUG [groot.core.healthcheck.reactor] - added mesos-slave[http-0:http]-0> to health table
Oct 23 04:03:29 node2 grootd: DEBUG [groot.core.healthcheck.reactor] - added mesos-slave[http-0:http]-0> to health table
Oct 23 04:03:29 node2 grootd: DEBUG [groot.core.healthcheck.reactor] - added mesos-slave[http-0:http]-0> to health table
Oct 23 04:03:29 node2 grootd: DEBUG [groot.core.healthcheck.reactor] - added mesos-slave[http-0:http]-0> to health table
Oct 23 04:03:29 node2 grootd: DEBUG [groot.core.healthcheck.reactor] - added mesos-slave[http-0:http]-0> to health table
Oct 23 04:03:29 node2 grootd: DEBUG [groot.core.healthcheck.reactor] - added mesos-slave[http-0:http]-0> to health table
Oct 23 04:03:29 node2 grootd: DEBUG [groot.core.healthcheck.reactor] - added mesos-slave[http-0:http]-0> to health table
Oct 23 04:03:29 node2 grootd: DEBUG [groot.core.healthcheck.reactor] - added mesos-slave[http-0:http]-0> to health table
Oct 23 04:03:29 node2 grootd: DEBUG [groot.core.healthcheck.reactor] - added DFSZKFailoverController[tcp-0:tcp]-0> to health table
Oct 23 04:03:29 node2 grootd: DEBUG [groot.core.healthcheck.reactor] - added DFSZKFailoverController[tcp-0:tcp]-0> to health table
Oct 23 04:03:29 node2 grootd: DEBUG [groot.core.healthcheck.reactor] - added NodeManager[tcp-0:tcp]-0> to health table
Oct 23 04:03:29 node2 grootd: DEBUG [groot.core.healthcheck.reactor] - added NodeManager[tcp-0:tcp]-0> to health table
```

Comment: It depends on which system you are running.

Comment: perhaps the application that generate this log also manage the rotation ?

Answer (score 2):

Just type
**sudo grep messages /etc/logrotate.d/***

On my system this returns
**/etc/logrotate.d/rsyslog:/var/log/messages**